# CakePHP: Display view in Lightbox?

Tags: cakephp, lightbox, thickbox

I am looking for a way to display a view in a lightbox or thickbox in Cakephp.

Is there a way how I could do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it ~

You'll want to create a new layout, that only includes the CSS and formatting required for the lightbox view.

```
function show_lightbox($id) {
    $this->layout = 'lightbox';
    $this->set('page_content', $this->Model->read(null, $id));
}
```

and create links to this content, as you normally would in another view with the appropriate lightbox `rel` or `class`, not forgetting to include the JS/CSS for the lightbox.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('View in lightbox', 
                               array('action'=>'show_lightbox', 1),     
                               array('class'=>'lightbox-link', 'rel'=>'lightbox')
                             );  
/* <a href="controller/show_lightbox/1" 
    class="lightbox-link" rel="lightbox">View in lightbox</a>*/
?>
```

Comment: Hm, I was trying it but I don't get it to work.

I made a layout file (lightbox.ctp) only having the css and js script inside.

Then I made a view file (show_lightbox.ctp) - I believe here is my mistake, but I don't know what else to do.

Could you help me out a little more please?